# Hochschild cohomology of (generalizations) of Khovanov's arc algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, geometric-representation-theory

Backgroud: In his seminal paper [A functor-valued invariant of tangles](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0103190), Khovanov (among many other things) introduced the arc algebra $H^{n}$ and several functors between $H^{n}$ and $H^{m}$ related to tangles. In particular, Khovanov homology of links could be recovered from these functors/bimodules.

Stroppel defined a generalization of Khovanov's arc algebra in [Parabolic category O, perverse sheaves on Grassmannians, Springer fibres and Khovanov homology](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608234) by considering arcs with "semi-infinite" ends and the resulting algebra is denoted by $\mathcal{K}^n$. Brundan and Stroppel generalized these algebras further in [Highest weight categories arising from Khovanov's diagram algebra I: cellularity](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1532), such as $K_{m}^{n}$.

As these papers suggest, the algebras $K_{m}^{n}$ are important for geometric representation theory. [Some more recent work](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.07624) shows the connection between such algebras and annular Khovanov homology.

Question: Do we have some concrete computations of Hochschild cohomologies of the algebras $H^n$ and $K_{m}^n$? Certainly we can compute everything out by writing some computer programs, so the question is really about patterns/geometric intepretations of the Hochschild cohomologies in these cases.

Comment: Is it possible to generalize the technique of Diogo-Lisi and compute symplectic cohomologies instead?

Comment: That's possibly true, but it is know that the total rank of Hochschild cohomology of the ordinary arc algebra grows exponentially w.r.t. $n$. To compute the differentials, one needs to compute GW invariants inside some Hilbert scheme, and actually we need some precise information about curves avoiding a divisor. The extended version is some kind of FS category, whose HH* may not have nice "closed-string" cousins.